# Excel vba set style in new sheet with a table

Tags: excel, stylesheet, vba

How do I rectify this code?
I would set style in new sheet but for this code gives 1004 error

```
Sub test()
Sheets.Add.Name = "new"
ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 3)) = "test"
ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 3)), , xlYes, , "TableStyleMedium7").Name = "sk"
End Sub
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: set style in new sheet but for this code gives 1004error

Comment: @sajad what are you trying to do with this line `Sheets("new").DeleteSheets.Add.Name = "new"` ???

Comment: @ShaiRado now right edited

Comment: It works for me as written in Excel 2016.

Comment: @sajad I think I might have simulated your error, try the code below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only reason I could simulate your error, is in case you already have a sheet named "***new***" in your workbook. If that's the case, try the following code below:

```
Sub test()

Dim sht                     As Worksheet
Dim shtNewExists            As Boolean

shtNewExists = False

' loop through workbook sheet to search if "new" already exists
For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    If sht.Name = "new" Then
        shtNewExists = True
    End If
Next sht

' is sheet "new" doesn't exist then create one
If Not shtNewExists Then Sheets.Add.Name = "new"

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("new")

sht.Range(sht.Cells(1, 1), sht.Cells(3, 3)) = "test"
sht.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, sht.Range(sht.Cells(1, 1), sht.Cells(3, 3)), , xlYes, , "TableStyleMedium7").Name = "sk"

End Sub
```

Comment: thank's for your answer but for this line errore:
<code> ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 3)), , xlYes, , "TableStyleMedium7").Name = "sk"

Comment: tanks for your answers